# Suche ein Wort aus der Verwaltungssprache

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche ein Wort, bei dem ich mir recht sicher bin, dass ich es in deutscher Sprache schon einmal gehört habe, ich versuche es mal zu beschreiben:

Wenn ein Supermarkt absichtlich mehr Ware bestellt, weil man davon ausgeht, dass Produkte geklaut werden.
Ähnlich wie ein "Kollateralschaden".
Ich glaube man sagt Umgangssprachlich auch, wenn man etwas verloren hat, sowas wie "Ach das sind 20% XXX, das ist in Ordnung".
Ich glaube das Wort endet auf -verlust und kommt aus der Verwaltungssprache.

Comment: »Zehn Prozent Schwund sind normal« ;)

Comment: Die Produkte werden nicht geklaut, sondern an der Steuer vorbei verkauft. Passiert auch nicht im Supermarkt, bei 10% könnte der dichtmachen.

Comment: Suchst Du nun ein Wort für den Schwund oder für den Sicherheitspuffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich würde Schwund oder als zusammengefasstes Wort Warenschwund verwenden. Auch wenn es nicht auf -verlust endet.

Zitat [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwund)

> Der Schwund oder Schwinden bezeichnet:
>
> - Allgemein das Verschwinden oder ein Abnehmen
> - ...
> - Umgangssprachlich das betrieblich nicht registrierte Verschwinden von Gütern aus Lagern oder Vorratsräumen, z. B. durch nicht erfasste Lagerentnahmen, Beschädigungen oder Diebstahl

[Gablers Wirtschaftslexikon](http://wirtschaftslexikon.gabler.de/Definition/schwund.html):

> Gewichtsverlust einer Ware infolge Lagerung (Lagerverluste), Umpackung oder Beförderung. Schwund wird im Handelsverkehr vom Verkäufer z.T. bei der Berechnung des Gewichts berücksichtigt.
>
> Kostenrechnung: Schwund als Ursache für Lagerverluste wird zumeist als kalkulatorisches Wagnis erfasst.
>
> Transportversicherung: Schäden durch natürlichen Schwund (Eintrocknen) gehören zu den nicht gedeckten Beschaffenheitsschäden.

Ein [Zeitungsartikel](http://www.sz-online.de/nachrichten/schwund-ist-immer-3021673.html)

> **Schwund ist immer**
>
> Firmen leiden unter Diebstahl. meist langen die eigenen Mitarbeiter zu. Dagegen scheint kein Kraut gewachsen zu sein.
>
> ...
>
> Besonders leidet demnach der Handel. Die Inventurdifferenz – also der Unterschied zwischen den Waren, die im Lager sein sollten, und denen, die tatsächlich da sind – liegt laut einem Bericht des Instituts EHI bei rund einem Prozent des Umsatzes. Das entspricht etwa der schmalen Gewinnspanne in der hart umkämpften Branche.

Die [Wirtschaftswoche](http://www.wiwo.de/unternehmen/handel/diebstahl-barometer-einzelhandel-verliert-fuenf-milliarden-euro-pro-jahr/12534834.html):

> Einzelhandel verliert fünf Milliarden Euro pro Jahr
>
> ... Demnach verursacht Warenschwund jährlich einen Schaden von fünf Milliarden Euro. Das entspricht 1,08 Prozent des deutschen Einzelhandelsumsatzes. Zwei Drittel des Schadens entstehen dabei durch Ladendiebstahl (4,3 Milliarden), etwa auch durch professionelle Banden. Es folgen Verluste durch administrative Fehler (19 Prozent), Diebstahl durch unehrliche Mitarbeiter (11 Prozent) und Betrug des Herstellers oder Lieferanten (5 Prozent).
>
> Mit seinen 1,08 Prozent liegt Deutschland im Mittelfeld. Weltweit büßen Einzelhändler 1,23 Prozent ihres Umsatzes durch Warenschwund ein - das entspricht 93 Milliarden Euro.

Comment: Bruch, Schwund, Verderb...

Answer (score 7):

*[Bestandsverlust](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Bestandsverlust.html)* (engl. [inventory shrinkage](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shrinkage)) ist der Begriff, den du suchst.

Answer (score -2):

Ergänzend zu den anderen Vorschlägen (v.a. Schwund) hier noch eine Variante

> Schlupf

Also beim Supermarkt etwa:

> Wir müssen von den Gurken 10 Prozent mehr bestellen, weil wir da immer so einen enormen Schlupf haben.

Zugegebenerweise wäre so eine Ausdrucksform eher in mündlicher Kommunikation zu erwarten, nicht in schriftlicher.

Abgesehen davon frage ich mich, wer eigentlich Gurken klaut. Aber die Zeiten ändern sich, und die Menschheit ist schlecht. In meiner Heimatstadt war zuletzt die öffentliche Meinung enorm erregt, weil jemand zwei Hühner aus einem Garten gestohlen und am benachbarten Grillplatz gebraten hatte. Indiz dafür waren die am Grillplatz vorgefundenen Federn. Die Staatsanwaltschaft ermittelt.

Der Hühnerhalter verzeichnete diesen Monat einen 33prozentigen Schlupf.